# Installing C++ compiler with no admin permission

Tags: c++, windows

Note: In my original question I asked about Code Blocks, so that's why people are talking about it.

I have a home PC with Visual Studio (2019) installed on it. But as I got a new laptop in school where I'm not the administrator, I would like to compile my C++ code on it as well. I tried to install "MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows" but it requested admin rights and my school administrator didn't want to give me them. What options do I have then?

Comment: Have you tried [clang](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html)? Worst case you could install it on your home computer, zip the install directory, and copy it to your laptop.

Comment: Without admin rights, it's unlikely that it will be possible to install something as substantive as an entire C compiler.

Comment: This question is offtopic, but you can use Visual Studio Code. It can be installed in User mode and I believe there is an extension for C++ support.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Actually, I don't see why a compiler should require administrative privileges.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm afraid it is not us that can help you with this; you should talk to your school's IT professionals.

Comment: A mere compiler shouldn't. But we're talking Microsoft Windows.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz While I certainly agree, I think it's more that installing _any_ software tends to be an admin task for various reasons. Nobody's saying you need to be admin to _use_ the software.

Comment: Code::blocks comes with *some* version of MinGW and it has no-setup downloads. Might be worth trying

Comment: The installation of components of the compiler probably require admin privs to be installed in protected locations.  The debugger probably needs special privs granted during installation by the installer (although sometimes the debugger first-run fixes up its privs, which at that moment requires elevated admin privs for a moment).  After installation, general compiling shouldn't require admin privs.

Comment: For the sake of the people who own the laptop (i.e., your school) please just ask them for help with this. If they don't want you to have a compiler on there, they're entirely entitled to stop you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download the 7z file from :
`https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/`

If you intend to install the windows version,
click the `x86_64-posix-seh` from MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0, and just uncompress the 7z file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yksisarvinen states in the comments section above - you could download codeblocks. The non-admin zip file includes a C++ compiler. Probably the quickest way through.

You can find it here - http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries

Comment: Seems to no longer be the case nowadays

Answer (score 0):

Msys2 provides user installers which don't require admin. Check them out.